# Iterator NPE in java

Tags: java, if-statement, iterator

I'm having an issue with multiple NullPointerExceptions, I'm getting one for my if statements within iterators and I can't figure out why

one of the problem blocks:

```
public int removeAllBooks(String author, String title){
Iterator<Book> itr=library.iterator();
int i=0;
while(itr.hasNext()){
        Book book=itr.next();
        if(b.getAuthor().equals(author)&&(b.getTitle().equals(title))){
            itr.remove();
            i++;
        }
        if(i>0){
            return i;
        }
     }
return 0;
```

}

The NPE error points to my if-statement line for some reason.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide the stack trace? Not sure about NPE, your code is vulnerable to ConcurrentModificationException for sure.

Comment: Is this your real code? I am asking since you are storing data in `book` reference, but your condition uses `b` reference. Also as mentioned in previous comment you should post stacktrace. To correct or add more informations to your question feel free to use [edit] option (it is placed below your post).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `b`? Where is it declared/initialized? Your `itr.next()` is assigned to the `book` variable, not `b`.

You code should probably be :

```
    Book book=itr.next();
    if(book.getAuthor().equals(author)&&(book.getTitle().equals(title))){
```